# pygame move with rectangle leaves a line

Tags: python, pygame

I have this problem. I have rectangle and if I move it it wont delete that
rectangle before leaving a line

```
import pygame as pg
from map import Map
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))
        pg.display.set_caption("Pacman")
        self.x = 360
        self.y = 520
        self.speed = 20
        runGame = True
        pg.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, (255, 255, 0), [self.x, self.y, 40, 40])
        while runGame:

            map = Map(self.gameDisplay)

            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    runGame = False

                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_w:
                        self.y -= self.speed
                    elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                        self.x -= self.speed
                    elif event.key == pg.K_s:
                        self.y += self.speed
                    elif event.key == pg.K_d:
                        self.x += self.speed
            pg.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, (255, 255, 0), [self.x, self.y, 40, 40])
            map.renderMap()
            pg.display.update()




pg.init()
main = Main()
```

This is what it creates in image [problem in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4MzG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code

```
import pygame as pg
from map import Map

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))
        pg.display.set_caption("Pacman")
        self.x = 360
        self.y = 520
        self.speed = 20
        runGame = True
        while runGame:

            map = Map(self.gameDisplay)

            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    runGame = False

                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_w:
                        self.y -= self.speed
                    elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                        self.x -= self.speed
                    elif event.key == pg.K_s:
                        self.y += self.speed
                    elif event.key == pg.K_d:
                        self.x += self.speed
            self.gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
            pg.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, (255, 255, 0), [self.x, self.y, 40, 40])
            map.renderMap()
            pg.display.update()




pg.init()
main = Main()
```